# how to change the picker view selected object colour in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

How can change the selected element colour in uipickerview. have 10 elements in picker view they are all black colour .when selecting an one from 1 to 9 means the selected element want to show in blue colour. but the last element selected means it want to show red colour. how can i achieve this help me.

Comment: can u show ur code it is easy optimize the code

Comment: I am using picker view delegate functions https://github.com/sebamisc/UItableViewWithPicker use this sample project and create a picker view now i want to change the colour. help me

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [arrayNo addObject:@"1"];
    [arrayNo addObject:@"2"];
    [arrayNo addObject:@"3"];
    [arrayNo addObject:@"4"];
    [arrayNo addObject:@"5"];
    [arrayNo addObject:@"6"];
    [arrayNo addObject:@"7"];
    [arrayNo addObject:@"8"];
    [arrayNo addObject:@"9"];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    UIView *view = [pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];

    UILabel *selectedLabel = (UILabel *) [view viewWithTag:1002];

    if ([[arrayNo objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:[arrayNo lastObject]]) {
        [selectedLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    } else {
        [selectedLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [arrayNo count];
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    if (view) {
        NSLog(@"view exists");
    } else {

        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [view setTag:1001];

        UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(pickerView.frame), 30)];
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [lbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [lbl setTag:1002];
        [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [lbl setText:[arrayNo objectAtIndex:row]];

        [view addSubview:lbl];

    }


    return view;

}
```

Comment: can give any sample code for this.. its helpful to me

Comment: Hi saravanaa check the sample code this is excatly same what you want.

Comment: - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    
return [[_arr_tags valueForKeyPath:@"results.tags"] count]+1;

}

Comment: - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    int val =[[_arr_tags valueForKeyPath:@"results.tags"] count];
    if(row==val)
    {
        return @"Delete image";
    }
    else
        return [[_arr_tags valueForKeyPath:@"results.tags"] objectAtIndex:row];
}

Comment: - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    int val =[[_arr_tags valueForKeyPath:@"results.tags"] count];
    if(row==val)
    {
       getpic_val=@"Delete image";
    }else
    {
       getpic_val=[[_arr_tags valueForKeyPath:@"results.tags"] objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

Comment: - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    int val =[[_arr_tags valueForKeyPath:@"results.tags"] count];
    if(row==val)
    {
         tView.text=@"Delete image";
        tView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }else
    {
        tView.text=[[_arr_tags valueForKeyPath:@"results.tags"] objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return tView;
}

Comment: these all my code can u help me how to implement ur code. delete image is last element its always in red colur. another values get from webservies. the value send to picker means it make blue colur anotherwise it is in black colour

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
for(UIView *lview in pickerView.subviews) {
    if ([lview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",lview);
}
}
```

By using the above code you will get all the sub view and check wheather it is label or not.

Then try to put different color to each label and then you find to your specific label, then you can do what ever you need.

The subviews order may change depending on the number of component in the picker.So, not added the exact logic.